# Why this promise is never resolved? (Simple JavaScript in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
async function test(){
  setTimeout(function(){return 1}, 100)
};
test().then(console.log); // Never displayed
```

If the setTimeout wrap is removed, it works:

```
async function test(){
  return 1;
};
test().then(console.log); // Displayed
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){return 1}, 100)` <-- `setTimeout` does not return a `Promise`, and even if it did your function does not `await` it.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please [edit] your question and add it to tags, so that the question can be answered.

Comment: @VLL JavaScript in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

First, you forgot the return statement in the `test` function. Without a return statement, the function returns a `Promise` which resolves to `undefined`.

Second, `setTimeout` does not return a promise. Instead, you have to create it explicitly.

It should be something like this.

```js
async function test() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 100))
}
```

But your code is equivalent to the following because you do not use `setTimeout` in any way.

```js
async function test() {
  return undefined
}
```

There are two options to create an async function. Historically the first one is that function accepts a callback. The second option is to return a promise from the function.

Many library functions accept a callback and call the callback when the async event happens. An example of such a function is the `setTimeout`.

To use a function which accepts a callback with `await`, you can wrap it in a new Promise.

For example, we have a library function `libFunc(..., callback)` where `callback` is a function which accepts some arguments.

You can create a new promise like this.

```js
const result = await new Promise(
  (resolve) => libFunc(/*some arguments*/,
    (callbackArg) => resolve(callbackArg)))
```

You can check my post on the topic [Async function from callback in JavaScript](https://victorsmirnov.blog/asynchronous-functions-from/)

Answer (score 0):

The below function does not return anything. Neither is it a promise, that it would resolve with a value. It is just a function that sets a timer for a function that (will run in window's context) and return 1. The returned value is not captured anywhere.

```
async function test(){
  setTimeout(function(){return 1}, 100)
};
```

To access the value from setTimeout you will have to wrap it in a promise and let the promise resolve with that value.

```js
async function test(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => setTimeout(function(){resolve(1);}, 100));
};
test().then(console.log);


async function test2(){
  return 1;
};
test2().then(console.log); // Displayed
```

Another way to access value inside setTimeout, without using promises is to pass callbacks like below.

```js
async function test(callback){
  setTimeout(function(){callback(1)}, 100)
};
test(console.log);
```

The above code shows why it is easier to reason about code with promises. Any piece of code, which you want to have access to the value (from inside setTimeout) will have to be in the callback. This gets messy

Comment: So the `setTimeout` logic must happen inside a Promise object, right?

Comment: Yes. Or you have to pass callbacks. I have mentioned the other way too

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation of the `callback` way. I understand now. So my return statement is just for the anonymous function inside the `setTimeout`, right?

Comment: Yes. And as i said when it will run in the global context nothing will capture it. That is why the callback is used.